# get active textview or activity using IME android

Tags: android, api, android-activity, ime, hwnd

Im developing an IME for android. I want to get the activity or textview control information while using my IME program. Like Hwnd property in win32 API or sender property of focused control in .Net .

Is there  any possible API available?

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks.
Sha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any possible API available?

No, because "the activity or textview control" is in another process, not your process.

Answer (score 1):

No, like they said its in another process.  However, you can get an InputConnection which will allow you to get some of the data from there (such as text, cursor position, etc).